# Infinity of Natural Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove the infinity of the Natural Numbers just be using this definition: (Bartle Analysis Book) "A set B is finite if it is empty or if there is a one-one function with domain B and range in an initial segment of N"

Using this definition I need to prove that is not possible to form a bijection between N and the initial segment of N, however, I do not really know how to start solving this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the range of the function is an initial segment of $\Bbb N$, there must be some number $c$ that is greater than any element of the range.  Now look at the image of the numbers from $0$ to $c$ (assuming you accept $0$ as a natural).  There are $c+1$ of them and only $c$ numbers in the range.